# jQuery: better do $('#elem') or var x = $('#elem') in iterations?

Tags: jquery, performance, iteration

This is an efficiency question. I've tested in some way with my Chrome, but I don't know for other browsers.

there are some variables that influence the result, for example:

- the number of iterations to do
- the dimension of the variable: $('.elems') is not the same as $('#elem').
- DOM structure

The test i've done is here: [search by id](http://jsfiddle.net/nery89/gdb6H/1/), [search by class](http://jsfiddle.net/nery89/gdb6H/1/)

```
for (j=0;j<med;j++){

    start = new Date().getTime();
    pippo = $(target);
    for (var n = 0; n < maxCount; n++) {
        pippo.css({height:'45px'});
    }
    elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    result1 += elapsed;


    start = new Date().getTime(); 
    for (var n = 0; n < maxCount; n++) {
        $(target).css({height:'45px'});
    }
    elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    result2 += elapsed;
}
```

Results seems to say that storing the variable is better than do every tyme the search.

What is your opinion?

For my browser I had a 20-30% speed-up when storing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the element in your example is selected by `id`, it should be unique in the page. Therefore you should always cache it before the loop.

```
var $pippo = $('#pippo');

for (j = 0; j < med; j++) {    
    start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var n = 0; n < maxCount; n++) {
        $pippo.css({ height: '45px' });
    }
    elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    result1 += elapsed;
}
```

If the selector was a `class` then you would need to define the selector within the loop, or better still use `each()` as it iterates over a single selector.

Comment: the example is with an id, but you can change the target to ".null", istead of '#pippo', to see the other result: [search by class](http://jsfiddle.net/nery89/qwYuq/3/), [search by id](http://jsfiddle.net/nery89/qwYuq/2/)

Comment: No problem, I noted at the end of the answer for using class selectors.